# NoClassDefFoundError generated from Spring Tool Suite wizard

Tags: java, spring

I was instructed to make use of the STS (Spring Tool Suite) for a java course I am enrolled in.  I have downloaded STS version 3.9.3 with platform Eclipse Oxygen 3 (4.7.3).

When I start up STS, I do the following:

1. Click File -> New -> Import Spring Getting Started Content
2. I do a search on rest
3. I select rest services with a code set of initial and complete
4. Once the application is generated, I navigate to the gs-rest-service-complete/src/main/java/hello subdirectory and I see Application.java, Greeting.java, and GreetingController.java.
5. I click on the green run button and I get the following output in the console:

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/Assert
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:263)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:247)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
   at hello.Application.main(Application.java:10)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.Assert
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   ... 5 more
   ```

I did not make any modifications to any configuration settings or any code.  I am brand new to this application and java programming. Why would I be getting this error?  How do I resolve it?

Thank you.
Jonathan

Comment: What build type you choose Maven/ Gradle?

Comment: @SounakSaha I did not change any setting on the wizard.  Build Type is defaulted to Maven.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Maven build type, you need to do this steps in your project.

- Right click on gs-rest-service-complete project >> Run As >> Maven Build/ Maven install 
     This steps will take few minutes to download all spring boot related jar. Make sure that maven build/install is successful.
- After maven build successful right click on Application.java >> Run As >> Java Application / Spring Boot App 
  Make sure 8080 port no application is running
- You can test the rest call by 'http://localhost:8080/greeting' URL

Comment: When i right click on gs-rest-service-complete and then click on Run As, I see Maven Build, Maven Build..., Maven clean, Maven Generate Sources, and Maven Install.  When i click on the first Maven Build, I am presented with a Edit configuration and launch dialog.  The same thing when I run the second Maven Build.  When I run it as Maven Clean, I get a BUILD SUCCESS but I also get a Warning: The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.  Even though that file does exist

Comment: And when i run it as Maven Install, I get a compilation error: No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? And I also see this at the bottom: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project gs-rest-service: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Comment: Yes, Choose Windows >> Preference >> Java >> Installed JRE >> Add your JDK location

Comment: I see an installed JRE, jrs1.8.0_121 (default).  I do not see any way to add a JDK here.  I clicked on Search and navigated to c:\program files\java and saw 3 folders, jdk-9.0.4, jre1.8.0_121, and jre-9.0.4.  I clicked on the jdk-9.0.4 but it returned a No JRE's found in C:\program files\Java\jdk-9.0.4

Comment: Install proper JDK version from below link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html

Comment: It turns out the Spring Tool Suite is not compatible with Java 9 or 10.  I uninstalled Java 10, installed Java 8, removed Spring Tool Suite, uninstalled all versions of eclipse, deleted my workspace, rebooted my computer, downloaded 64 bit version of Sprint Tool Suite again, set it up, generated the application, and it executed.